# MongoDB shell not running commands

Tags: mongodb, command-line, mongo-shell

I installed the mongo shell and when I try to run a command (even mongo --version) it returns this error:

'2020-04-29T17:39:25.320+0300 E  QUERY    [js] uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
@(shell):1:5'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create a MongoDB database and started the service?

Comment: To run `mongo --version`, you do not need any service running of course. Can you give more details? Which operating system you use and which mongo version you are trying to use?

Comment: In some consoles, you need to use "./" for executables, i.e `./mongo --version`

Comment: `./mongo` means "execute mongo in your current directory". Most likely mongo binaries are stored in /bin/mongo or /sbin/mongo - typically not the current directory.

Comment: Thank you very much for your responses. The problem was that I was putting the command in the mongo shell instead of the command line (cmd). I am a total newbie on this.